# PDF transformation for y=|x|

Tags: distributions, data-transformation, random-variable, density-function, cumulative-distribution-function

Suppose I have the random variable X with a pdf: 
$$f(x)=exp(-(x+1)) u(x+1)$$
where u is the unit step function; such that u = 0 for x<-1 and u=1 for x>-1

$$y= |x|$$

for $$-1<x<1$$
 otherwise y=0

I need to find the PDF and the CDF for the variable y.

My trial is:
First y possible values are between 0 and 1.
Second is we have 2 values of x for each y.

Thus, using the fundamental theorm:
PDF of y  = f(x1)/|dy/dx1| + f(x2)/|dy/dx2|

where x1 is between -1 and 0 and x2 is between 0 and 1

so $$f(y)= - exp(-(-y+1)) u(-y+1) + exp(-(y+1)) u(y+1)$$

For the CDF of y:
$$ F(Y)=P(Y <y) = P(|x| < y) = P(-y < x < y) = Fx(y) - Fx(-y)= Fx(y) - (1-Fx(y)) = 2Fx(y) - 1 =  2(1 - exp(-(y+1)) u(y+1)) - 1 = 1 - exp(-(y+1)) u(y+1)) $$

Can you please comment on my solution and correct it if mistaken?

Comment: At the end you seem to conflate $F$ with $f.$  Certainly there's no general closed form formula for $F$ in terms of $f,$ because you have't stipulated anything about $u.$

Comment: Ops! Just edited my question. u is the unit step function

Comment: So does $u(x+1) =1$ when $x \gt -1$ and $u(x+1) =0$ when $x \lt -1$?

Comment: Yes, exactly, I edited the question to clarify that

Comment: If $X$ has a drifted exponential distribution on $(-1,\infty)$ why do you restrict $Y=|X|$ to be supported on $(-1,1)$?

Comment: That is how the question is :/